# How do I store certain content/names, and then bring it up again?

Tags: c++

I am just getting started with c++, and I am practicing some basic code. I am asking the user to input their name, so I can greet them back while repeating their name. How would I write that specific line? Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter your name: " << endl;
```

Comment: You've learnt of `cout`, now learn about [`cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin)

Comment: Check `cin`. Also please have a look at the Tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour and take care to format any code that you post.

Comment: Using main function arguments might be handy in here.

Answer (score 2):

If you wan't to save your name, you need to create a variable, and than set value to this variable from input:

```
int main()
{
   cout << "Please enter your name: " << endl;
   string name; // you should use string type to save text
   cin >> name; // getting name from user's input
   cout << "Hello, " << name << endl; // Now you can use your name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The program is done but, you can also go *further* and make a:

#### Struct of people Data

Do you want an example on how to make it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

struct People {    // Making a struct
    char name[20];  //  to save the name
    float  height;  //  to save the height of the person
} person;           //Obj name (the name of the struct user)



using namespace std;
int main()
{   
                                // You have to name your structure to use it in the main 

    cout << "Hi enter your name: " << endl;
    cin >> person.name;                         // You are getting name from user's input

    cout << "Hello, " << person.name ;      // The name is saved and reused

    cout << ", How tall are you? \n";   // You can get also decimals numbers
    cin >> person.height;                   // Gettin' the height

    cout <<"\n\nSo you are "<<person.name<<" and "<<person.height<<" tall!";    //resuming

}
```

## Structs what are?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)),

> A struct in the C programming language is a composite data type (or
> record) declaration that **defines a physically grouped list** of
> variables **under one name** in a block of memory, allowing the different
> variables to be accessed via a single pointer or by the struct
> declared name which returns the same address. The struct data type can
> contain other data types so is used for mixed-data-type records such
> as a hard-drive directory entry, or other mixed-type records.

To make an example:

```
struct [structure tag] {                    struct Books {
                                                    
   member definition;                           char  title[50];
   member definition;                           char  author[50];
   ...                                          ...
   member definition;                           char  subject[100];         
} [one or more structure variables];        } one_book;
```

If this answer makes you
satisfied then mark it like solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the whole name into one string you can use,

```
#include <string>


string name;
getline(cin, name);
```